# Nginx set up to redirect connections from http to https. However, request to http server gets blocked. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am setting up a reverse proxy that redirects http connections to https. However, when I try to make a request to an http server hosted on a docker container it gets blocked (MIXED CONTENT).

I tried to add the upgrade-insecure-requests header, but it gives me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I imagine this is because I don't have a SSL certificate associated with it. As a result I created a self signed certificate and I modified the nginx configuration in the docker container to use it, but the web page doesn't even load.

I want to know if there is any other way to solve this. Doesn't need to be a working solution, just some ideas I can play with to see if I can reach a valid solution.

Comment: If we can see your nginx configuration we can maybe help much better. If you want to have a working solution you can't just use a self-signed certificate (or you need to accept this inside your browser). If you want to make this website public you need a certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority like letsencrypt. To achieve this you might want to have a look at certbot. https://certbot.eff.org/